# How a NFT token is linked with Asset (ex. image, video)

Tags: solana

I am currently looking to connect a NFT token to image. I had uploaded image file to ipfs. I have public  url and contract ID. But, now I want to attach "w5Zuvk3SspOFPJY$5qq"  this sample token to image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.